# Extent of CSS3 support in JavaFX

Tags: css, javafx, javafx-8

What is the extent of CSS3 support in JavaFX? According to documentation

> JavaFX Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) is based on the W3C CSS version 2.1 [1] with some additions from current work on version 3 [2]

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#introscenegraph
Cannot find anything specific here.

1) However how much percentage of CSS3 is supported in JavaFX?

The CSS3 specification must have come along way since this was first mentioned in the JavaFX CSS specifiaction.

2) What from CSS3 is supported?

There is only one mention of CSS3 in the JavaFX CSS specification.

3) Is it possible to use SASS with JavaFX CSS?

4) What changes does Java 9 have in regards of CSS support?

Comment: I'm not good enough with CSS to answer the question, but I can at least point you to [the official JavaFX 8 CSS reference page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html).

Comment: Yes, I read that, but it does not say exactly how much of CSS3 is supported. It only states that some additions from current work on version 3.

Comment: [CSS3 is huge and ill-defined](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS3).  Much of it, such as the working drafts, is not implemented by major web browsers or even fully specified at this stage.  JavaFX implements very little of it (that may or may not matter for you).  It impossible to advise what you should do without seeing your stylesheet.  I suggest, instead of asking here, that you try converting your existing stylesheet for use in JavaFX.  If that effort is straight-forward and goes well for you, then great, if not, then you have a useful datapoint for yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although this is a 2yo question, I will answer for the sake of people. There is so little information about JavaFX css and sass, so I hope this answer will be of a help to someone.

1+2) I don't know the exact percentage but my experience with CssFX shows that very little original css3 code got into my css files. Most of the attributes are CssFX ones. Furthermore, there are many css3 attributes that defined on some JavaFX component, but not on others. I suggest you just learn it while going.

3) Yes, it is possible, and I did it just now in my current project.
Sass is a powerful framework to use with css, but eventually, the sass compiles the sass/scss code to a regular css, which can be used in your JavaFX app. just use the CssFX attribute in the sass code instead of the standard css3 attributes.

I'm using eclipse, so I've downloaded [LiClipse](https://www.liclipse.com/) from the market, which lets me view my .scss files from within their eclipse built-in editor. Sometimes I use [SublimeText](https://www.sublimetext.com/) instead because of its extra tools.

About the sass/scss to css compilation, as I'm working with Maven, I use the maven-sass-plugin (specifically [this one](https://github.com/Jasig/sass-maven-plugin)) to compile my project's scss files every time that I run my application. In addition, I've added to my project a builder, which compiles my scss files every time that a scss file has been changed ([Sass builder example](https://ducfilan.wordpress.com/2017/01/25/how-to-auto-compile-sassscss-files-in-eclipse/comment-page-1/))

4) This is a question about Java 9 css support, which is barely related to the main topic of this question - which is JavaFX css - and should be asked as another topic.